# Can't POST to a webserver from an iPhone using a PHP script

Tags: php, iphone, xcode, networking, nsurlconnection

Well I am pretty new to both iphone and PHP development, and am trying to simply post an image locally on to my webserver (i have setup the webserver already). From some reason, my PHP script is being executed, though the file is not being saved.

I am sure that this is the most basic problem here, but I just cant seem to find the problem. Would REALLY appreciate you guys' help. Thanks!

My objective-c code:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"13.png"];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 90);
NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost/uploader.php";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[request setTimeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\";filename=\"myfile.jpg\"\r\n"] 
                  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

My PHP script:

```
<?php
$target = "./upload/";
$target = $target.basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']) ;
$check = getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], './upload/')) {
    echo "YES";
}
 else
  echo "NO";

?>
```

Those are the values that I get when printing these variables in PHP:

```
print_r($target);

./upload/myfile.jpg

print_r($check[0]);

320

print_r($_REQUEST);

Array
(
)


print_r($_FILES[userfile]);

Array
(
    [name] => myfile.jpg
    [type] => application/octet-stream
    [tmp_name] => /private/var/tmp/phpWJE4UC
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 8829
)

print_r($_FILES[name]): 

(empty)

print_r($_FILES[type]);

(empty)

print_r($_FILES[tmp_name]);

(empty)

print_r($_FILES[error]);

(empty)

print_r($_FILES[size]);

(empty)

print_r($_FILES);


Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => myfile.jpg
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /private/var/tmp/phpMvJ4oR
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 8829
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your move call is incorrect. You must specify a filename for the destination. You've only provided a directory, so the call fails. PHP will not create a filename for you, you must specify it yourself.

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], './upload/name_of_file_to_write')) {
                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, Marc, but I am getting the same behavior - "move_uploaded_file" fails. I was not sure about the name of the file that I should create, but just to be on the safe side, I called it the same name, i.e.,: './upload/myfile.jpg' and created one of course. Thoughts?

Comment: Make sure your webserver has permissions to create/write files  in that upload directory. Check the PHP error log to see if there's anything come up as well. If a file of the same name exists, make sure the webserver can overwrite it.

Comment: sorry for the silly question - but how can I check that the webserver has the right write permissions? Thanks so much.

Comment: `ls -ld uploads` from a shell prompt. `var_dump(stat('./uploads'))` from inside php (see http://php.net/stat)